# How did some server members obtain Protection 255 on my Minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

On my server, several members have been caught obtaining items with Protection 256 and/or other high-level enchantments. They don't have any rank that would allow them to do this.

What are some possible ways that these users could have obtained these high-level enchantments? I would like to know so that I can prevent them from abusing this in the future.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about cheating in multiplayer games [are off-topic here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/489/185203).

Comment: @pppery From [a comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/398892/how-to-get-protection-250-in-minecraft-servers#comment560470_398898) from the asker on one of the answers, it appears that they have provided context that was not present before. It states that they were not wanting to cheat, but had asked this question to find out how someone _else_ cheated on their own server. I will rephrase the question to reflect that.

Comment: ... but those are actually the same question. An answer explaining how this was done necessarily tells future readers how to do it, and thus "turn[s] Arqade into a place where you can get answers to questions regarding cheats in multiplayer games".

Comment: @pppery You do have a point there. This is an unfortunate situation, where the asker does not have the intent to cheat, but any answers that come in can be used by people who *do* have a bad intent. However, I do see an additional comment below: *"I'd clarify that this should only apply to things that the games terms of use or creators view as cheating. There are a lot of "cheap" things that some people think are cheating but the game creators have officially stated they have no problems with."* I have trouble telling whether that second comment would change anything. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: It doesn't change anything, as the answer is presumably exploiting a bug in Minecraft, or some third-party server mod. That line of reasoning would make, questions about e.g. Infiniobsidian (which the developers explicitly said they wouldn't go out of their way to fix) on-topic, but does not work here.

Comment: @pppery You can do this with a simple `/give` command. I don't think it is fair to assume that people will automatically turn to cheats, especially when any cheats that could achieve this are giving the cheater operator powers.

Answer (score 1):

Only up to protection level 4 is obtainable in survival. The only way to get anything higher than that would be the /give command (which on a server, only Admins would have access to). So I guess try to get one from them? But likely they would only do so if you paid for a rank.

Comment: Thanks, I was asking why some users on a server managed to do it and I wanted to know how to stop them from abusing  this

Answer (score 0):

## You can't.

It's impossible to get these items through regular gameplay without resorting to modifications or save editing *even* if you are an admin of the server.

You'll need to either edit your save data serverside with programs such as NBTExplorer, or use a plugin (for Bukkit/Spigot/Paper/Sponge) servers that allows you to manipulate items; both which require access to the server backend (usually as an owner/admin).

That or do what the server wants you to do and <s>pay up</s> donate.

Edit: You can with `/give` but more "custom" items may not fit in a chat box and require a command block to execute.

Comment: Thanks, I was asking why some users on a server managed to do it and I wanted to know how to stop them from abusing this

Comment: "That or do what the server wants you to do and pay up donate." - isn't giving custom items to people who donate against the Minecraft EULA?

Comment: @pppery yes, but Mojang's enforcement is iffy at best.. That was one of the arguments brought up even they released 1.19.1. Go look up a server list and you'll see.